# How to see alternate routes and traffic on Here drive+ (nokia- drive)

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, here

In the windows shop when I downloade the new version of here drive for nokia lumia 920 I saw pictures of traffic featuresa and alternate routes in case of traffic.
I can't figure it out, it just follow the route it choose and does not show traffic or let me see alternate routes.

Do those features really exists and how to activate them?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if/how HERE Drive+ taks traffic into account when routing, but I do know that you can use the round button with the two cars on it (it should be in the lower left corner of the screen) switches you to the mode that shows traffic on the map and back.

Answer (score 0):

Since today alternative routes are presented after choosing a destination and before starting navigation. Swiping left and right sets the route.

Comment: I'm not seeing that option - could you add a screenshot of this feature?